# execute Update() of statement not working in servlet while update the records

Tags: java, servlets

In this code, i tried to update row in oracle db but executeUpdate() not works.It also not give   any error on stacktrace.I create a project with the help of this link:https://www.javatpoint.com/crud-in-servlet.all code is same.Help is appreciated.

```
    public   static int edit(StudentBean obj) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    int i=0;
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  

    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","root" );
    PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("update uc set name=?,mobile=?,email=?,dob=? where id=? ");
    stmt.setString(1, obj.getName());
    stmt.setString(2, obj.getMobile());
    stmt.setString(3, obj.getEmail());
    stmt.setString(4, obj.getDob());
    stmt.setInt(5, obj.getId());

    i=stmt.executeUpdate();

     con.close(); 
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }System.out.println("in dao clss +"+i+obj.getName());
    return i; 
}
```

Comment: check what does `obj.getId()` have in it .

Comment: it gives 0,but why?

Comment: does your table have row with id `0` ?

Comment: no,but i set id from servlet to bean class and then fetch it.

Comment: maybe that's the reason update is not working , because it is not able to find any id with `0` value and `where id=?` never become true . check if `id` is set properly in your `beans`

Comment: thnx, problem is in servlet class,not getting id value but now solved.